How do I add a new column to an existing table in R?
I have a dataset with 5 possible categorical responses for several different columns: "An extreme amount", "A great deal", "A moderate amount", "A small amount" and "None". For this specific column, there were no responses for "An extreme amount" or "A small amount", which is causing me to get a table with only 3 columns.
A great deal     A moderate amount    A small amount 
           19                    24                17 

I want to add two columns to this table with headers "An extreme amount" and "None" that both have values of 0 in the table so that I can pass it into a chisq.test() function. Here is the code I used to create the table:
Concentration <- table(Concentration_Two_Weeks)

I tried using the "cbind" function to add columns to the table with this code:
Concentration <- cbind(Concentration, c(0,0))

and got the following output:
                  Concentration  
A great deal                 19 0
A moderate amount            24 0
A small amount               17 0

I also tried using the cbind function on the original data set with this code:
Concentration <- table(Concentration_Two_Weeks)
Concentration <- table(cbind(Concentration_Two_Weeks, c(0,0)))

and got this output:
          0      A great deal A moderate amount    A small amount 
           60                19                24                17 


the first code block you have is a named vector, not a matrix, frame, or table.

Welcome to SO, Zachary Gines! This is a great first question! Please share your data in a more usable state, though, so we can be confident what is being shown here in the question. For this, please [edit] your question and paste the output from dput(Concentration_Two_Weeks) into a [code block]. Thanks!

If this is your data frame
df <- data.frame(col1 = 
       c(rep('A great deal', 19), 
         rep('A moderate amount', 24), 
         rep('A small amount', 17)))

Since table uses factors to build a contingency table, get the right output by changing the column vector col1 to factor with all desired levels
df$col1 <- factor(df$col1, levels=
                    c("A great deal", 
                      "A moderate amount", 
                      "A small amount", 
                      "An extreme amount", 
                      "None"))

Using table
table(df)
col1
     A great deal A moderate amount    A small amount An extreme amount 
               19                24                17                 0 
             None 
                0


I think @Andre's answer is the correct way to approach this by setting factor levels at the data.frame itself.
But, to answer your question as posed, adding an extra value to a one-dimensional table without stripping it of being a table object is actually not that straightforward.
Using Andre's example data again:
df <- data.frame(col1 = rep(c('A great deal', 'A moderate amount', 'A small amount'), c(19,24,17)))
Concentration <- table(df$col1)

str(Concentration)
## 'table' int [1:3(1d)] 19 24 17
## - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 1
##  ..$ : chr [1:3] "A great deal" "A moderate amount" "A small amount"

As you've noticed, cbind doesn't work as it will add a new column rather than new values to the table:
##                  Concentration  
##A great deal                 19 0
##A moderate amount            24 0
##A small amount               17 0
##Warning message:
##In cbind(Concentration, c(0, 0)) :
##  number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2)

Just using c() kind-of works, but it strips the table class out:
Con_c <- c(Concentration, c("An extreme amount" = 0, "None" = 0))
Con_c
##     A great deal A moderate amount    A small amount An extreme amount 
##               19                24                17                 0 
##             None 
##                0 
str(Con_c)
## Named num [1:5] 19 24 17 0 0
## - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:5] "A great deal" "A moderate amount" "A small amount" "An extreme amount" ...

So you have to recast it as a table if that is strictly needed.
Con_c2 <- as.table(c(Concentration, "An extreme amount" = 0, "None" = 0))
##     A great deal A moderate amount    A small amount An extreme amount 
##               19                24                17                 0 
##             None 
##                0 
str(Con_c2)
## 'table' num [1:5(1d)] 19 24 17 0 0
## - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 1
##  ..$ : chr [1:5] "A great deal" "A moderate amount" "A small amount" "An extreme amount" ..


Use $ or other method accepted by data frame (or whatever your data is):
concentration <- data.frame(
  a = 19,
  b = 24,
  c = 17
)

names(concentration) <- c("A great deal", "A moderate amount", "A small amount")
concentration
#>   A great deal A moderate amount A small amount
#> 1           19                24             17

concentration$`An extreme amount` = 0
concentration$None = 0

concentration
#>   A great deal A moderate amount A small amount An extreme amount None
#> 1           19                24             17                 0    0

or dplyr::mutate():
concentration |>
  dplyr::mutate(`An extreme amount` = 0, None = 0)
#>   A great deal A moderate amount A small amount An extreme amount None
#> 1           19                24             17                 0    0

Created on 2024-04-04 with reprex v2.1.0
